# WordPress Params url rewrite doesn't function after upgrade

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, seo, url-rewriting

I have the follow problem: When I upgraded Wordpress to 3.8.1, the URL rewrite doesn't function like `http:\\mysite.com\page\myparam` but now function only like this    `http:\\mysite.com\page\?param=myparam`

I have searched in the documentation and various similar questions, but I haven't fix.
And this plugin: `qstring-parameter`, Rewrite and Rewrite analyzer (this last find my url configuration)

What can I do?

My host is LAMP, PHP version is **5.2**  and Wordpress is **3.8.1**.

The last code I tried is:

```
function my_flush_rules(){
    $rules = get_option( "rewrite_rules" );

    if ( ! isset( $rules["(regione)/(\d*)$"] ) ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}



function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules["regione/(\d*)$"] = "/index.php?page_id=88&region_nn=$matches[1]";
    return $newrules + $rules;
}


function my_insert_query_vars( $vars )
{
    array_push($vars, "region_nn");
    return $vars;
}
```

I've fixed: i removed all custom field in page editor

Comment: So it was working to the prior version `3.8.0` or `3.7`?

Comment: it could be 3.7 but i'm not secure (it was installed in august 2013), but i'm secure it wasn't 3.8

Comment: You mean **sure**? not **secure** right? :)